# Uneven distribution of requests on ALB nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Why is there an uneven distribution of requests among the ALB nodes in different Availability Zones, even though cross-zone load balancing is enabled, and the default routing algorithm is round robin? The node in AZ1 is receiving 25k requests, while the other two nodes in AZ2 and AZ3 are getting 30k requests each. Can you help understand the factors contributing to this uneven distribution?

stickiness is disabled…